# Proportion distribution of DC and ACs within JPEG files

Tags: jpeg

When I observing the JPEG files with specific quality factor, I want to analyse the Proportion distribution of DC and ACs. i.e, I want to know how much size the DC and ACs take up within JPEG files, respectively. Is there any public revelant statistical data ? Or how can I do it by myself ?

Comment: Your question is not very easy to understand... maybe you could click [edit] and clarify? What is a *"bytes size distribution"* please - I thought all bytes were the same size at 8 bits. What are you hoping to find/deduce? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I have corrected the title and added more descriptions about my question.

Comment: You can see the coefficients listed if you use `exiftool -v -v -v IMAGE.JPG`, example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69357163/exif-i-cant-calculate-the-orientation-of-the-images/69358014#69358014

Comment: Thanks. But it seems that `exiftool` cannot show the proportion of DC ? i.e. size of all DC / size of JPEG file.

Comment: Sorry, I still have no idea what you are trying to do.

Comment: A jpeg file actually is binary stream, which consist of the coding of DC coefficients and AC coefficients. I want to know the proportion of the DC coefficients in the bitstream, how much size those DC coefficients take. Sorry for my unclear expression.

Comment: There's only one DC coefficient, all the others are AC.

Comment: Yes, one DC for one $8 \times 8$ block, I mean the DC coefficients of all blocks.